# Xampp running very slow sometimes

Tags: xampp

Why my xampp running very slow sometimes
I have also tried to restart my pc but its not working

I see that suddenly Apache starts ports are by default: 80 and 443. But after few seconds they change to one or several ports: 61145, or 34543,22345,54321 (or similar)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy6Ct.png)